# Pythonic way to write a series of non-cascading if statements

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, enumeration

So I have this code I wrote to read from information from twitters REST API using tweepy and I'd like to collect a lot of information without exceeding the rate limit.  This question is more of a conceptual one than tweepy-related.  So far this is the only way i've thought of doing it:

```
for i, tweet in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name = "@twitter").items(1400)):
    print(i, tweet.author.name)
    if i == 200:
        time.sleep(180)
    if i == 400:
        time.sleep(180)
    if i == 600:
        time.sleep(180)
    if i == 800:
        time.sleep(180)
    if i == 1000:
        time.sleep(180)
    if i == 1200:
        time.sleep(180)
    if i == 1400:
        sys.exit()
```

But rather than writing a bunch of if statements, is there a more pythonic way this can be written? Or if it isn't broken don't fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, tweet in enumerate(...):
    if i % 200 == 0 and i > 0:
        time.sleep(180)
```

This will fire every multiple of 200 except for 0.

Comment: So the % is helping to say "whenever idx is divided by 200 and the remainder is 0" and "idx has to be > 0" then sleep?  And why does it grab 201 items and not 200 for each iteration?